# Why are the values of a js array overwriting themselves?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem when I try to assign values to a js array, I mean, I can check that I'm iterating all the elements but when I assign the value the size where I place that value doesn't change... 
This is the simplified html:

```html
<div id="HotelAccordion0">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" id="cabeceraTarifas">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
               <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#HotelAccordion0" href="#collapse1" class="" aria-expanded="true">

               <i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-up pull-right"></i>
                    Standard -  <span class="precioMasBajo">Desde <strong>50,00 €</strong></span>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" id="cabeceraTarifas">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#HotelAccordion0" href="#collapse2" class="collapsed" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-up pull-right"></i>
                    Vista Jardin -  <span class="precioMasBajo">Desde <strong>70,00 €</strong></span>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" id="cabeceraTarifas">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#HotelAccordion0" href="#collapse3" class="collapsed" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-up pull-right"></i>
                    Doble + Supletoria adulto -  <span class="precioMasBajo">Desde <strong>82,80 €</strong></span>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

This is 1 object, then, for example, I have another one:

```html
<div class="panel-group smart-accordion-default" id="HotelAccordion1">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" id="cabeceraTarifas">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#HotelAccordion0" href="#collapse1" class="" aria-expanded="true">

                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-up pull-right"></i>
                    Standard -  <span class="precioMasBajo">Desde <strong>40,00 €</strong></span>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" id="cabeceraTarifas">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#HotelAccordion0" href="#collapse2" class="collapsed" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-up pull-right"></i>
                    Vista Mar-  <span class="precioMasBajo">Desde <strong>200,00 €</strong></span>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" id="cabeceraTarifas">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#HotelAccordion0" href="#collapse3" class="collapsed" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-up pull-right"></i>
                    Doble + blablabla -  <span class="precioMasBajo">Desde <strong>90,95 €</strong></span>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

So I need to take the first value, the lowest number (came from the back ordered by `minPrice`), what I am able to do, but one value is stacking each other in the variable memory(?), this is how I retrieve only the value:

```js
var preciosHotelesArray = [];
var numberPattern = /\d+/g;

for (var i = 0; i < whatever.length; i++) {
        var precioMinimoPorHotel = $("#HotelAccordion" + i + ">.panel.panel-default:first-child").map(function () {
        return this.innerText.match(numberPattern).join(',');
        console.log(precioMinimoPorHotel);
        preciosHotelesArray[i] = this.innerText.match(numberPattern).join(',');
    }).get();    
}
```

And here all values are stacking each other, whatever I see only last value are inside the array?, What I am doing wrong??

**-------WORKING EXAMLE---------**

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Qiqke/tnupLka4/)

So now only displays 50. And it should display `{0:50, 1:40}`.

Thank you very much!!.

Comment: You should really add a minimal working example of your code which clearly shows the faulty behaviour.

Comment: You're calling ```return```, which exits the function. The code after ```return``` is unreachable.

Comment: You should also format your code snippets before pasting them into your questions.

Comment: @Tim, thank you, thats a point jajaja...

Comment: Thank @TimVN, was enough with your point of view jajaja...I did like this: `for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
                 $("#HotelAccordion" + i + ">.panel.panel-default:first-child").map(function () {
                    preciosHotelesArray[i] = this.innerText.match(numberPattern).join(',');                  
            }).get(); 
        }` . I would like to use the `return` keyword but its okey like this. Really thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You should move the line with `return` to the end of the function, after adding the value to the array

Comment: Thank you Zamfi!